# Green's formula on a positively oriented simple closed contour

Tags: complex-analysis

If C is a positively oriented simple closed contour, use Green's formula to show that the area of the region enclosed by C can be calculated as $$\frac{1}{2i}\int_C \bar{z}dz$$

I approached this problem by writing down $\int_C zdz = \int_C (u+iv)(dx+idy)$ and applying Green's formula to get $\int \int(-v_x+iu_x-u_y+iv_y)dxdy$.  I also applied Green's formula to $\int_C \bar{z}dz$ to get $\int \int(v_x+iu_x-u_y+iv_y)dxdy$.

I don't see how to get from the point that I am at to $\frac{1}{2i}\int_C \bar{z}dz$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{1}{2i} \int_C \bar{z}\, dz = \frac{1}{2i} \int_C (x - iy)(dx + i\, dy) = \frac{1}{2i} \int_C (x\, dx + y\, dy) + i(x\, dy - y\, dx).$$

Since $x\, dx + y\, dy$ is exact,

$$\int_C (x\, dx + y\, dy) = 0.$$

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{2i} \int_C \bar{z}\, dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_C (x\, dy - y\, dx).$$

Now if $R$ is the region enclosed by $C$, by Green's theorem, the last expression equals

$$\frac{1}{2}\iint_R \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-y)\right)\, dx\, dy = \frac{1}{2} \iint_R (1 + 1)\, dx\, dy = \text{Area}(R).$$

Comment: Thanks.  As soon as you said "$x\, dx + y\, dy$ is exact" it clicked and I was able to solve it.

Comment: @Snagglewhen great! I'm glad it clicked. :-)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “exact”? I have not seen this term used in complex analysis (a cursory google search seems to be referencing PDE’s).

Comment: @JaneDoe I mean that $x\, dx + y\, dy = df$ for some function $f$.